It depends on how you view this. In French
Souvent, on dit « dépendre à qqch. »
Mais si j'ai envie de dire « cela dépend comment tu le vois. » pour traduire it depends on how you view this, est-ce que j'ai besoin de la préposition à ?

Je crois qu'on dit plutôt "dépendre de qqch" dans ce cas. "Dépendre à qqch" ne me paraît pas correct dans cette situation. On ne peut pas dire "dépendre à comment tu le vois".
Pour ce qui est de "cela dépend comment tu le vois", on peut utiliser de ou l'omettre. Les deux sont possibles, sans que la nuance soit très grande. L'absence de préposition ferait partie d'un langage un peu moins soutenu (voir discussion ici).
Le TLFi montre bien que dans le sens de l'exemple de l'OP, seule la préposition de est acceptable.
Quant à la phrase "cela dépend à qui tu demandes", ce à n'introduit pas un complément du verbe dépendre, mais bien du verbe demander: à qui tu vas demander. Le complément de dépendre ici est toute la phrase à qui tu demandes, et est introduit sans préposition, comme on peut souvent le faire pour le verbe dépendre.
(voir aussi cette réponse sur les constructions avec le verbe dépendre).

Je tiens à remercier @jlliagre pour les compléments qu'il a bien voulu partager.

I

dépendre à qqch

Comme dans sa présentation cette question fait des rapprochements avec une forme connexe qui n'a vraiment pas grand chose à voir avec le vif du sujet, mais qui indique une confusion possible, voyons d'abord de quoi il en retourne en ce qui concerne cette forme (« dépendre à qqch »).
Dans la combinaison « dépendre à qqch », la préposition « à » n'introduit pas un cod de
« dépendre », mais cette combinaison se trouve quand même parce que la préposition habituelle (« de » )  n'est pas utilisée (omise) ;  « ça dépend à » est très souvent utilisé ; on le trouve avant les  pronoms et déterminants interrogatifs.

qui, que, quoi, quel, quelle


Le fait que « à » soit beaucoup moins fréquent n'enlève rien au nombre des occurrences de « à », que l'on trouve par dizaines: « à ».
II
Il n'est donc pas du tout question de « à » dans la question mais de « de ».
Il est possible  de se passer de la préposition « de »  ; cela est devenu est devenu correct, et la tendance vers l'acceptation a peut-être commencé il y a assez longtemps, mais cela est un autre sujet.
Grammaire de la phrase française - Livre de l'élève - ...
Pierre Le Goffic · 2014 :


percontactif, Wiktionnaire
Une percontative est une interrogative indirecte : philo-lettres.
Il est néanmoins toujours correct d'utiliser « de » (pour les personnes qui ont un sens prononcé des relations grammaticales, le manque de la préposition « de » donne une impression d'erreur).

cela dépend  comment tu le vois.

Dans ce cas aussi, il est possible de ne pas utiliser « de » et c'est la forme sans « de » qui est plus fréquente. Mais il n'y a aucune possibilité d'utilisation de « à ».

Donc, il n'est pas nécessaire d'utiliser « de », mais c'est possible et pour certaines personnes ce sera la seule forme correcte.

cela dépend (de) comment tu le vois.


de et à n'introduisent pas les mêmes compléments. Dans l'exemple donné par l'OP, on ne pourrait pas substituer à à de.

@Frank Je ne dis nulle part que « de » et « à » introduisent les même compléments ; d'où est-ce que vous sortez ça ?

@LPH Relis ta réponse. Tu commence par C'est exact. alors que non, Dépendre à quelque chose n'existe pas.

@jlliagre « Ça dépend à qqch » est une combinaison quelconque, même si le « à » n'est pas grammaticalement lié au verbe « dépendre ». « Ça dépend à quoi il pense. » : « quoi il pense » est qqch. Je ne vois pas ce qui cloche ; ça pourrait peut-être être dit d'une façon plus élaborée, mais c'est tout. Cet utilisateur cherche la petite bête mais il ne veut pas la montrer ?

@LPH En grammaire, verbe + préposition + quelque chose a un sens bien défini. Ça dépend à quelle heure est bien sûr une phrase qu'on entend mais elle ne rentre pas dans ce moule. Tu peux si tu veux inventer une nouvelle terminologie mais précise le alors dans ta réponse.

Les dizaines d'exemples pour à sont-ils offerts en soutien à une réponse à la question précise de l'OP sur la phrase "cela dépend comment tu le vois"? Parce que c'est l'impression qu'on a quand même, et dans ce cas, ce serait faux.

@Frank Non, évidemment, ce ne sont que des précisions préliminaire du fait que l'entrée en matière de la question est assez vague et que ça aussi pouvait être rendu un peu plus spécifique.
